# SQL server find dependencies between tables that are not declared

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

Recently I got a database that contains the live data of a web-application.

By reviewing it I found that there are many tables that have dependencies i.e. already implied but not declared.

For example :

`TableA` have columns `[Id], [Name], [Address]`. Here `[Id]` is `primary key`.
`TableB` have columns `[Id], [TableAId], [Salary]`. Here `[Id]` is `primary key`, and column `[TableAId]` contains only values of `[TableA].[Id]` (not any value except TableA's Id), but it is not declared as a foreign key.

By Reviewing code, I found that both of the table's record are inserted in same event. So `[TableB].[TableAId]` column will have only values that `[TableA].[Id]` contains.

Now, I want to find the other dependencies like them.

Is it possible using SQL server query, tool or any third party software?

Comment: you might consider some Data Mining tools

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, I don't think you can count on TableA.Id to imply a foreign key reference to TableA. It *might* be referring to a *different* table that *also* stores id numbers from table A. I know you've reviewed the code in this specific case, but you're looking for a solution that doesn't require reviewing the code.

Anyway . . .

You can join tables on expressions. This query (PostgreSQL syntax) joins part of the column name to table names. In PostgreSQL, the function call `left(t1.column_name, -2)` returns all but the last two characters of t1.column_name; `left(t1.column_name, -3)` returns all but the last three. That's intended to match names like "TableAid" and "TableA_id".

```
select t1.table_catalog, t1.table_schema, t1.table_name, 
       t1.column_name, left(t1.column_name, -2), 
       t2.table_catalog, t2.table_schema, t2.table_name
from information_schema.columns t1
inner join information_schema.tables t2
        on left(t1.column_name, -2) = t2.table_name or 
           left(t1.column_name, -3) = t2.table_name
where t1.column_name like '%id';
```

I believe this query will return the same rows. It's using SQL Server syntax, but I haven't tested it in SQL Server.

```
select t1.table_catalog, t1.table_schema, t1.table_name, 
       t1.column_name, left(t1.column_name, length(t1.column_name) - 2), 
       t2.table_catalog, t2.table_schema, t2.table_name
from information_schema.columns t1
inner join information_schema.tables t2
        on left(t1.column_name, length(t1.column_name) - 2) = t2.table_name or 
           left(t1.column_name, length(t1.column_name) - 3) = t2.table_name
where t1.column_name like '%id';
```

Both these might return rows incorrectly, mainly because joins probably need to take into account the "table_catalog" column at the very least. I debated whether to include it. I finally decided to leave it out. I think that, if I were in your shoes, I'd want this query to have the maximum chance of returning some surprising rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try some dependency checks.

```
--- Get the source objects, columns and dependent objects using the data.
select so.name as sourceObj
     , so.type as sourceType
     , c.name  as colname
     , st.name as coltype
     , u.name  as DependentObj
     , d.selall   as is_select_all
     , d.resultobj as is_updated
     , d.readobj   as is_read
     --, d.*
  from sys.columns c 
     ----- object that owns the column
 inner join sys.objects so on so.object_id = c.object_id
 inner join sys.types st on c.system_type_id = st.system_type_id
     ----- holds dependencies
     inner join sysdepends d   on d.id = c.object_id
 ----- object that uses the column
 inner join sys.objects u on u.object_id = d.depid
```

You can list all the tables/views/procs, etc. The bits that are really good for your use case are:

```
     , d.sellall   as is_select_all
     , d.resultobj as is_updated
     , d.readobj   as is_read
```

If any of these fields have 1, they are either selected, updated or retrieved directly.

I hope this may help a bit.
Enjoy